# Webdriver -> how to check something in txt file open in firefox?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

My problem:

- 1. open http://www.webscorer.com/resources/templatestart using `Firefox`
- 2. click on `txt` file
- 3. using `autoIt` on dialog box I check `open in Firefox`
- 4. `txt` file opens in new `Firefox` window

My question:

How to check content of this `txt` file opened in new `Firefox` window?

Comment: Assert that Driver.FindElement(ByCssSelector="pre").Text.Contains("what you want") or (would be better) download file and use programming language methods to read file content

Answer (score 2):

Because you're opening a new tab in your browser, you can follow this pattern.

1. Once the tab is opened, make Selenium switch its focus to it. If you don't know how, [this question has got several answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver) or elsewhere.
2. Apparently, Firefox puts the file content in a `<pre>` tag so you have a valid HTML document. So it's easy to use `driver.findElement` to get the contents in the tag.
3. You now have the whole file's contents to do the string operations you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a text(.txt) file in a browser and check the structure of the contents in the console, you will notice that it's HTML and the content of the file are enclosed within `<pre></pre>` tag.

So what you can do is switch to the new tab (since you are opening the file in new tab) and then user `getText()` to fetch the content of the `<pre></pre>` tag.

Here is a sample code I tried and it worked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WebDriver driver;
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
            //driver = new ChromeDriver();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://localhost/1/test.html");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            String s = null;
            driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList (driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window((String) tabs.get(1));
            String filecontent = driver.findElement(By.tagName("pre")).getText();
            System.out.println(filecontent);

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```